# Move data from dataframe to vertica without staging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vertica

I am trying to push data from dataframe into a vertica table, currently I stage the data into a CSV and use COPY command to insert the data into final vertica table.
Is there a way to avoid the intermediate step of staging the data into a CSV or temp table and rather move directly from dataframe to vertica table?

*Current*:

**df.to_csv(my_file)
vertica_cursor.copy( "COPY vertica_table FROM STDIN PARSER public.fcsvparser(type='traditional',header=true,delimiter='|') abort on error no commit;", my_file)**

*Trying to acheive:*

**Insert into vertica_table
select * from df**

or

**MERGE into vertica_table
using df**

Can you please help if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

VerticaPy will be your friend here. It does have everything ready for you and these types of operations:

https://github.com/vertica/VerticaPy

it offers a "virtual data frame" - which keeps data within Vertica instead of memory - and can write back to table in Vertica